# Erro ao importar Model Django 3.1

Tags: python, django

Olá, estou tentando importar um model para usar dentro da minha View e estou tendo problemas, fiz um arquivo de teste para tentar importar antes de colocar o model na view. Já registrei o app, já fiz o "migrate" dele e mesmo assim ele diz que o model não foi encontrado. Tentei fazer o importe das seguintes maneiras:

```
from .models import *
from .models import ClassNameHere
from my_app.models import ClassNameHere
```

O meu model está no mesmo diretório do arquivo no qual vou usar ele. Segue meu código:

MEU ARQUIVO DE TESTE:

```
from student_base.models import Words

print('test')
```

Meu arquivo de settings do projeto:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'student_base',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'user_authentication',
    #autentication
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    #My windown loggin
```

Se eu tento importar o model e printar um "Hello, world" depois só pra ver se a importação tá ocorrendo, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Eu já registrei o app no settings como mencionei

Comment: acrescenta na pergunta a sua arvore do projeto, fazendo o favor

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

Pessoal, agradeço a ajuda. A resposta do Carlos Cortez me deu uma luz. Ele disse "bem, ele foi importado. Só não foi usado ainda" bom, eu sou novo em Django, estou aprendendo com a documentação. O que houve foi o seguinte:
Fiz todos os procedimentos corretamente, e, antes de tentar instanciar um objeto da classe do meu model na minha view, eu simplesmente criei um arquivo "test.py" onde eu fazia "from .model import myModelHere" e printava um "Hello word". Eu pensei "Se não aparecer nenhum erro, vai printar a mensagem e meu model foi importado com sucesso!". Esse foi o erro...Mas, quando apliquei na view, ele funcionou certinho.

Answer (score -1):

ao invés de:

```
From .models import *
```

usa letra minúscula:

```
from .models import ModelAlpha, ModelBeta, NomeQualquerModel
```

existe a possibilidade também do seu arquivo estar com nome diferente, então poderia ser:

```
from .model import *
```

caso nada disso dê certo, apague este arquivo .py que contém os modelos e crie outro. As vezes, quando vc cria algum arquivo e muda o nome dele depois dá uns problemas esquisitos que não valem muito a pena ficar tentando resolver. É mais fácil apagar e fazer outro. (Obviamente que vc vai copiar o conteúdo do arquivo antes, pra não precisar escrever tudo de novo.)

Edit1(complemento):

pode soar desrespeitoso, mas é que a pergunta está um pouco vaga, então algumas coisas precisam ser declaradas pra que se consiga chegar à uma solução pra sua dúvida.

Aparentemente no seu arquivo **views.py** vc está tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
from student_base.models import Words

print('test')
```

e a mensagem da qual está achando estranho é que o Model *Words* não foi importado.

bem, ele foi importado. Só não foi usado ainda.

Pra que vc faça uso dele, vc precisa 'codar', por exemplo:

```
from student_base.models import Words


def funcao_qualquer(request):
    context = {
        'palavras': Words.objects.all
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Veja que o model *Words* é usado quando orientado a fazer uma busca de todos os objetos à ele relacionado.

Sua pergunta diz:
"*Meu model não está sendo importado*", e isso pode acontecer. Mas devido ao formato da sua pergunta, este complemento de resposta é necessário.

Comment: O "from" está minúsculo, apenas escrevi errado. Tentei apagar o arquivo e refazer e também não deu certo. É estranho, é como se o Django não estivesse considerando que meu app devesse ser usado, como se ele não tivesse registrado no settings do projeto.

Comment: edita a pergunta com a mensagem de erro que está dando

Comment: Editei lá... mas ele dá o erro "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" ele não acha o models do meu app. Já fiz outro projeto do zero pra ver se era algum bug, deu a mesma coisa.

Comment: Talvez seja esse  "crispy_forms" não foi instalado no Django , referência: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html      tenta instalar.

Comment: Carlos, achei onde estava o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda! Olha lá minha resposta acima.

Comment: haha ok... q bom q funcionou